# Problems with using EXISTS in SELECT clause on DB2

Tags: sql, db2, exists

I have a little problem with using EXISTS statement in the SELECT clause. I have tables ITEM and SUBITEM and I want to return the boolean flag if there exists any subitem of given type:

```
SELECT item.id, item.f1, item.f2, item.f3,
    EXISTS(select sub.id from schema.subitem sub where sub.item_id = item.id
      AND type='standard') as has_standard
    FROM schema.item item
```

However, I get the error message:

> Error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "." was
>   found following ".".  Expected tokens may include:  ", )". 
>   SQLSTATE=42601 SQLState:  42601 ErrorCode: -104

The example is simplified and the table names are not real, it's just an example to ask for the syntax for EXISTS clause on DB2. As far as I remember, I had no problems using that syntax on PostgreSQL or Oracle...

Comment: What are the distribution of rows/row counts for these tables?  You might end up RBAR-ing (row-by-agonizing-row) the system if `item` is large, regardless of indices, due to the subquery being run per-result-row.  `LEFT JOIN`ing to a `DISTINCT`ed subquery may yield better performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a `case` statement around it:

```
SELECT item.id, item.f1, item.f2, item.f3,
       (case when EXISTS (select sub.id
                          from schema.subitem sub
                          where sub.item_id = item.id AND type='standard'
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as has_standard
FROM schema.item item;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item.id, item.f1, item.f2, item.f3, 
CASE when (select '1' from  schema.subitem sub
where sub.item_id = item.id AND type='standard')= '1' 
then '1' else '0' end has_standard from schema.item item;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.